# Handling AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I am doing an AJAX call from a function. Everything works fine until the AJAX call(I tried console.log before the AJAX call that was executed). It calls a controller's index function from there it returns the JSON object
in view:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url('/proposals');?>",
   data: form,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){ 
    //alert(data.id+'--'+data.msg);
    console.log("test");        
    if(data.msg == 'success'){
            var valueRemaining= $('#RemainingFunding').val() ;
        if (valueRemaining <= 0 ) {
            alert ('No Funds Remaining');
            return false;
        }
    var valueSubmitted =  $('#subtotal'+state).text();
    var valueSubmitted = parseInt(valueSubmitted);

    if (valueSubmitted != null || valueSubmitted != '') {
        //var substract = valueRemaining - valueSubmitted;  
        //$('#RemainingFunding').val(substract); 
    }
        //console.log( 'value of subtotao f = ' + subflt );            
        $('#ProposalId').val(data.id); //ajx_submit
        $('#sum').val(data.propsum);
        $('#ajx_submit').val(parseInt(tot_ajxsub)+1);
        $("input:radio[id=ProposalAnotherLocationY]").prop('checked', false);
        $('#fld_subtotal').val('0');
        pastSubtotals += flttot;
        console.log("test");
                    tableState=0;
        //console.log( 'value of pastSubtotal = ' + pastSubtotals);

        //$('#RemainingFunding'). val(intamtval);
    }else if(data.msg == 'error'){
        alert('Proposal budget can not be blank!!');
        return false;

    }else {
                alert('no match');
            }
   return false;           
       //$("#form")[0].reset();
       //Unterminated String constant fixed
   }

 });
```

Controller:

```
if ($this - > request - > isAjax()) {
    $Proposalsum = $this - > DftsProposalbudget - > find('all', array('fields' => array('SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy1) as cy1', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy2) as cy2', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy3) as cy3 ', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy4) as cy4 ', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy5) as cy5', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy6) as cy6', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy7) as cy7', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy8) as cy8', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy9) as cy9', 'SUM(DftsProposalbudget.cy10) as cy10'), 'conditions' => array('DftsProposalbudget.proposal_id' => $LastID, 'DftsProposalbudget.user_id' => $UID), 'group' => 'DftsProposalbudget.proposal_id'));

    $sum = 0;
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($Proposalsum, true).
    "</pre>";
    if (!empty($Proposalsum)) {
        foreach($Proposalsum[0][0] as $key => $value) {

            //echo $sum += $value['0']['cy1']; 
            $sum += $value;

        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'success', 'id' => $LastID, 'propsum' => $sum));
    exit(0); //json_encode('msg' => 'success', 'id' => '1');
```

In the network I get this message:

[image]

But it is not printing or working for anything that is in the block success.

Comment: where you have console.log("test"), what happens if you do console.log(data)? if success doesn't fire at all, is the net console showing an error?

Comment: Its in the first code segment line 8. It does nothing. It does not print anything in the console and in console there is no error. Thank you

Comment: ...but you can see the call in the network console? if so, it must be coming back as error. try an error handler add this after your success block : `error:function(obj status, error) { console.log(obj);console.log(status);console.log(error);}`

Comment: yes I can see the call in network console. I haven't tried error. Thanks! I am now trying this

Comment: I also had quite an issue while using $.ajax for json. But replacing it with $.getJson worked for me.

Comment: the network console should tell you if the status was `200 ok`. anything else goes to the error handler.

Comment: yes it says that 200 ok

Comment: are you getting notification of a Cross-origin block? CORS blocking still returns 200 ok

Comment: No I am not using cross-origin block

Comment: In case you do not actually have `echo '<pre>'.  print_r($Proposalsum,true)."</pre>"` in your non-debug attempt, please say so, or even better don't even post it, it's very tedious for people to figure what in your code you are actually using and what might cause problems.

Comment: cross-origin block isn't something you use, it's something that happens if you're trying to access json via a different sub-domain/ domain to that serving your page. have you tried adding the error block?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I am assuming that I have no problem in the code i have shared. May be the error is somewhere else although there is no error message. And the block you told me to add, I tried it but that gave me error. Whatever I really appreciate your eagerness to help. Thank you.